# Clear Gif image cache in SwiftyGif CocoaPod

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, gif, sdwebimage

I'm using **SDWebImage** to load web images of type png, jpg, jpeg... and **SwiftyGif** Pod for loading Gif images since SwiftyGif consumes less memory than other frameworks.

To clear the image cache,

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        SDImageCache.shared.clearMemory()
        SDImageCache.shared.clearDisk()
        SwiftyGifManager.defaultManager.clear()
}
```

`SDImageCache.shared.clearMemory()` and `SDImageCache.shared.clearDisk()` is working perfect and clearing the webimages cache for png and jpg images.

But `SwiftyGifManager.defaultManager.clear()` is not clearing the cache of Gif images. Is there any other way to clear cache of Swiftygif pod? Or please suggest a better Framework that loads Gif images and clear the  caches properly.